# Export Error to Excel Gridview Column with Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a `Gridview` like this picture. Easyly in my last column, i keep a note for that row. (Simply, i made it edit, select, update that gridview classic properties.)

[image]

As you can see, my last column has a `Textbox` (`Multiline`)

Here is my last column gridview code;

```
<EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTNOT" runat="server" Height="35" TextMode="MultiLine" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [T_NOT] FROM [TAKIP] WHERE T_HESAP_NO = @T_HESAP_NO ">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="T_HESAP_NO" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

And then i export this `Gridview` to excel with this code;

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TahTakip.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";


    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
  }
```

There is no problem since this step. The problem is when i open this excel file, `NOT` column is different the other columns. It has a `Textbox` like this picture;

[image]

I don't want to be a `Textbox` in my `Excel` file. Just want a normal cell with a NOT value like left column.

How can i do that?

Best Regars,

Soner

Comment: I have edit my answer, plz check and let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to export datatable instead your GridView as you have controls in gridview that can't be export to excel

**Edit:** you can do like..

```
protected void btnExportExl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=BusinessUnit.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);

    GridView grd = new GridView();
    grd.DataSource = datatable.DefaultView; // you get the datatable from DB that will not have controls!!!
    grd.DataBind();

    grd.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

please note, in the actual grid I have some image button and when I am exporting then I get the datatable again from DB

Comment: @Muhammed but i have a gridview. Can you tell me some example? Can i delete all textbox in Gridview when i exporting? Is it imposible?

Comment: you need to iterate your gridview when you are going to export. you have to remove your controls from particular columns and replace text in those columns. so you will get your all things

Comment: @Muhammed can i do that with this code for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
Control current = control.Controls[i];
if (current is Textbox)
{
control.Controls.Remove(current);
control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
}
}

Comment: I am trying to find some relatvie example, unable to found yet. but it should be like.

Comment: @Muhamemed i write this code with your code like http://i1103.hizliresim.com/2011/3/9/4380.jpg but still doesn't work. I delete databind because gridview has already a datasource. (SqlDataSource)

Comment: you need to get data from DB in dt, I have posted the commment; the code is not exporting Grid data instead it is exporting Datatable